# How do I "unlock" the movement and scaling? Whenever I transform an object, it moves/scales/rotates it by a set amount

Tags: transforms

Whenever I try to move/scale/rotate an object, it moves it by a specific amount (1 meter). How can I make it stop doing that and make it move freely?

Context:
(Video link) https://screenpal.com/watch/cZVlDqVJe9g

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)